# Notice: Use of undefined constant mysql_fetch_assoc - assumed 'mysql_fetch_assoc'

Tags: php, function, select, fetch

I'm not a php programmer. I manage this site: http://cambiocorsasrl.com/. Some days ago I moved it to another hosting provider and from there I get this error:

> "Notice: Use of undefined constant mysql_fetch_assoc - assumed
>   'mysql_fetch_assoc' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/axential000031/httpdocs/lib/myclass.php on line 49".

I tried with host but they told me that all is ok thier side.
This is the line 49 of myclass.php :

```
function select ($sql="", $fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc)
```

I tried to change line 49 to:

```
function select ($sql="", $fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
```

but I get this error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/axential000031/httpdocs/lib/myclass.php on line 49"

What do I wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance.
Roberto

Comment: 1. That code makes no sense. 2. `mysql_*` functions are obsolete, perhaps your new host does not support them.

Comment: You're getting the errors because neither of your two examples are valid PHP syntax. In fact, they demonstrate quite a big misunderstanding of how things work. This isn't the place for me to give you a full-on tutorial into the basics of programming, but suffice to say it looks to me as if you need to find a better tutorial than the one you're currently working with. (also note that the `mysql` functions are obsolete, so if you're using a tutorial that is recommending using those, then the tutorial is also obsolete)